# Accesing facebook data via RSS or JSON is possible?

Tags: json, facebook, rss, atom-feed

is any way to access the list of links publicated by my friends on facebook via RSS or Json (or any other standard format) ??

What information from my friends feeds on facebook can be access in standard format? (and how)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Their new [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) returns `JSON` objects for all requests.